# Error in job Build for constructing C++ program to determine range

Tags: c++, syntax

I was till was experiencing some issues until i made the change to my formula for gravity.  all is working now. thanks everyone. I appreciate all the great feedback

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cmath>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        // Initialize objects:

            double angle = 0.0;
        double velocity = 0.0; 
        double range = 0.0;
        const double PI = 3.141592653589793238;
        const double gravity = 9.8; //meters pers second

        // Input:

        cout << "takeoff angle: ";
        cin >> angle;
        cout << "Please enter velocity: ";
        cin >> velocity;

        // Process

        angle = angle * PI / 180;
        range = sin(2 * angle) * velocity * velocity / gravity;

        cout << " range " << range << endl;
        system("pause");

        return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
range = sin(* angle)*velocity pow(2);
```

This is not valid C++.

`pow` is a function that takes two arguments. x^y would be represented as `pow(x, y)`.

Also, `sin(*angle)` is invalid as `angle` is neither a pointer nor a class with a defined `*` operator.

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
range = sin(2 * angle) * velocity * velocity / gravity;
// (No need to use pow(velocity, 2) over velocity * velocity)
```

(This is the correct formula for range)

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Fixed formula and now im getting "Please enter angle: 2
Please enter velocity: 5
 range 1.#INF
Press any key to continue . . ."

Comment: Change the value of gravity to `9.8`. Multiplying it by velocity which happens to be `0` will lead to a division by zero, which causes the Infinity value to pop up.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `angle` as a double, so you don't want to dereference it by writing `*angle`.
`pow()` takes two arguments, so you probably want to write `pow(velocity,2)`.
`sin(angle)*pow(velocity,2)` should work. I'd recommend `sin(angle)*velocity*velocity`, as you don't need to use `pow(x,2)` if you only want to calculate `x*x`.

Oh, and note that gravity is 0.0 in your code, as it is defined as `velocity*9.8` while velocity is 0.0.

Comment: that's probably why im getting the results listed above, huh?  I'm trying to fix it..